# Asynchronous operation returning a result with method inheritance

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a simple question about asynchronous operations. I have a composition class used to encapsulate an `HttpClient` instance. This class have an abstract base class to avoid code redundancy.

My problem occur when I'm trying to override a base method doing a part of the job in the derived method who is doing additional operations.

To be clearer I have:

**Base method:**

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute a Typed GET Request and returning <typeparamref name="TResponse"/> result.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResponse">Response specified type.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="route">Uri string to request.</param>
    /// <param name="path">Path parameters to provide to the <paramref name="route"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="query">Query parameters to provide to the <paramref name="route"/>.</param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="Task"/> that represents the asynchronous operation containing <typeparamref name="TResponse"/> response object.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="HttpRequestException">Raised if the Http request failed.</exception>
    public virtual async Task<TResponse?> GetAsync<TResponse>(string route, Dictionary<string, string>? path = null, Dictionary<string, string>? query = null)
    {
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(BuildUri(route, path, query));
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<TResponse>(new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
    }
```

**Derived method:**

```
    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public override async Task<TResponse?> GetAsync<TResponse>(string route, Dictionary<string, string>? path = null, Dictionary<string, string>? query = null)
    {
        var token = await GetBearerToken();
        base._httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return base.GetAsync<TResponse>(route, path, query);
    }
```

So the base class method have the http request responsibility and the derived method is adding additional pre-treatments to configure the `httpClient` with the required headers and others.
The error occur on the return, I tried both:

```
return base.GetAsync<TResponse>(route, path, query);
```

with the error: Impossible to convert type `Task<TResponse?>` into `TResponse?`

and

```
return await base.GetAsync<TResponse>(route, path, query);
```

with the error: Impossible to convert type `TResponse` into `TResponse`?

I'm not understanding why, when I'm awaiting the result, a cast is done casting `Nullable<TResponse>` into `TResponse` in the derived method, knowing the fact that base method is returning `Task<TResponse?>`.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

[@Selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) and [@Enigmativity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/259769/enigmativity) got the right answer here adding a class constraint to the generic `TResponse` type in the method definition of both base and derived method resolve the issue, Thanks for your help!

Comment: You prolly need to add constraint to generic paremeter wich will force argument to be a reference type.

Comment: or just use `Task<TResponse> GetAsync<TResponse>()` and let user decide to use `GetAsync<Type>()` or `GetAsync<Type?>()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You method needs to constrain `TResponse` to a `class`:

```
public virtual async Task<TResponse?> GetAsync<TResponse>(
        string route,
        Dictionary<string, string>? path = null,
        Dictionary<string, string>? query = null)
    where TResponse : class
```